# install Gnome in ubuntu 15.10 along with unity

Tags: 15.10

i'm a new member in this community i hope i can get some useful information about my problem when i'm using ubuntu 15.10. right now i'm using 15.10 with unity and after installed i change to tty1 to install gnome DE with this command sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop. after installed i restart the system sudo reboot and i found out my screen turns grey color until choosing the OS. https://www.facebook.com/pendekar.sunnah/videos/912799848808854/?pnref=story this is the video i took the screen turns to grey color

1. how to change the screen on this video back to normal?
2. after gnome had installed, i found out many failure example i can't change theme, right click on the panel above and below, and maybe many more i will inform here if i find it. so what's the solution for my problem?

Comment: GNOME reskins GRUB. That isn't an issue; everything works exactly the same. The background color is different. Now, for the second issue, can you give a few more details? Where can you not do those actions? GNOME or Unity?

Comment: I have had no problems using `ubuntu-gnome-desktop`. Try to open the gnome tweaktool to fiddle with your settings if behaviors are not as expected

Comment: Requist: lol i don't know this version of ubuntu gotta try now thanks mate

Zacharee1: can i change to another color? well sorry i don't give you details from my question, in gnome that i have installed recently i can't change theme, right click panel above and below

elethan: i download tweak form Ubuntu Software Centre but the theme is same from unity i can't modify it not only that i right click desktop and there's no option for theme only background wallpaper

Answer (score 0):

You could also revert to both, and type this in the terminal:

```
 dconf -reset -f /etc/atp
 unity --replace-reset-icon & disown
```

and you have both environment.

Comment: sorry i don't know what command is this?